# Actual ChromeDriver is not compatible with Chrome v95

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The error that appears in starting, the program was working fine last weeks, I use Spring boot and Spring web, maybe was some upgrade in the browser:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of 
 ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 95
 Current browser version is 97.0.4692.71
```

Using pom with spring boot and it's default values does not work, how to refresh it to the last version?

My Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If I try to change dependencies to:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
<version>4.1.1</version>
```

It gives me warning:
*Gives warning:
Overriding managed version 3.141.59 for selenium-chrome-driver*

And it does not work anyway.

Already downloaded and executed ChromeDriver 97.0.4692.71 version from, nothing happens. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=97.0.4692.71/

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear:

> This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 95
> Current browser version is 97.0.4692.71

Your Chrome driver and Chrome browser major versions **must** match!

[download chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

If you want some way to semi-automate this from your Maven build, have a look at

- [driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Ardesco/driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin)
- [webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

Comment: Already made it, think it should be done in compilation time by pom.

Comment: @JamesB Added links to some resources.